# Multiple IP addresses on the same computer, initiated by one program, two NICs?

Tags: java, windows, networking, ip, nic

I have a crawler program that should run multiple threads each with a different IP address, about 10 threads simultaneously.

Is it possible to assign each thread a different IP address on a machine running Windows VII? With a Java program?

If so, can this be achieved by utilizing a machine that has multiple NICs?

I want to interface with these different IP addresses at the program level, is this feasible?

Comment: You should be able to assign each thread with the network interface. An each network interface should have different IP address.

Comment: Hi, is it possible you could please explain that a bit more explicitly?

Comment: It means nothing. Threads don't have IP addresses. Sockets do. @rcs needs to clarify his comment.

Comment: @EJP: I am saying that network interface that has IP address, not the thread. The thread is used to do operation with the network interface. For example, we can declare a class that extends from class Thread, and inside this class we have class `Socket`. You may want to take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html. One of the constructor allows you to specify the IP address of the network interface you are going to use. `public Socket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddr, int localPort)`

Comment: @rfs I'm aware of what the Socket documentation says. I've been reading it since 1997. What nobody was aware of was what your comment meant. You needed to clarify it. You don't need to patronise people who tell you so. It's the OP who has the programming  problem, not me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If your program uses Socket directly you can enumerate all the network interfaces and their IP addresses and use either bind() or the four-argument Socket constructor to bind to whichever local IP address you like.
- If however you're using URLConnection I'm not aware you can specify a local address in any way.
- I can't speak for HttpClient, but it has documentation you could consult.
- If you're using something else, this tedious guessing game will continue until you deign to confide in us further as to what it is.

Comment: Haha- thank you. 

I'm not being coy! I just don't know. I'm a research assistant, asking this question on behalf of my colleague!

Comment: So what's stopping you from asking your colleague the answer to the question?

Comment: CRITICAL UPDATE!
<should use 'HTTP URL Connection!

Comment: @user3787253 Critical to whom? There's nothing about HTTP in the question. As it's your question, if HTTP was critical to you, you should have said so in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the available nics by:

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nics = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
```

You can than use their InetAddresses to bind your threads to a specific nic.

Comment: Would I need any special libraries or anything to do that?

Comment: You did not tell which technic you are using to connect.

Comment: Maybe URL, Socket, ... For those you don't need additional libraries.

Comment: I'm a research assistant, and they asked me to find out if this is possible, which is to say... what do you mean by connect? such as 'ssh'?

Comment: could you possibly point me in the direction of some kind of sample program/code snippet?

Comment: @user3787253 What do *you* mean by connect? What technology are you using? TCP sockets? URLConnections? HttpClient? Other?

Comment: I mentioned three things and you did one of them, but it's irrelevant. Netsh isn't a connection technology. What are you planning to use to *connect to the target sites* and *download the data?*

Comment: ah, some program we wrote, it's a crawler, it just goes around clicking links and whatnot

Comment: @user3787253 Come off it. *Answer the question.* That 'some program' uses (a) TCP sockets (b) URLConnection (c) HttpClient (d) other, and if (d) please state what it is. You've been asked this at least three times, complete with most or all of these alternatives. You won't get an answer by withholding information, or by ignoring what you're told or asked here, as you've done several times now.